# Python copy and concatenate linked lists, preserve order

Tags: python, copy, linked-list, concatenation

I have a basic linked-list implementation in python. Each `Cell` has some data associated with it and a next object, used to include the rest of the linked list (and null if only the first param of data is given in the constructor).

I want to copy and concatenate two lists together, so that the final product preserves the order and is independent of the two original lists.

Here is what I have:

```
def list_concat_copy(A, B):
        C = Cell(A)
        while A.next != None:
                A = A.next
                C = Cell(A,C)
        C = Cell(B,C)
        while B.next != None:
                B = B.next
                C = Cell(B,C)
        return C
```

The issue that I am having is that this reverses the order:

```
A = Cell(8,Cell(9,Cell(10)))
B = Cell(11,Cell(12,Cell(13)))
C = list_concat_copy(A,B)
```

Now if I `walk_and_print(C)` I get `13 12 11 10 9 8`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not strictly needed to answer the question but...may I ask why you're using linked lists in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do some weird stuff:

```
A = Cell(8,Cell(9,Cell(10)))
```

suggests that your Cell is something like

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, val, nxt=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = nxt
```

but doing

```
C = Cell(A)
```

never copies anything, it just creates a new Cell with the same A as a value.

So, lets start with a Cell that can actually copy itself:

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, val, nxt=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = nxt

    def copy(self):
        if self.next is None:
            return Cell(self.value)
        else:
            return Cell(self.value, self.next.copy())
```

Now your concat is easy:

```
def concat_copy(a, b):
        new = a.copy()

        # find the end of the copy
        last = new
        while last.next is not None:
            last = last.next
        # append a copy of the other list
        last.next = b.copy()
```

For completeness, here is what your tried to do:

```
def copy( cells ):
    new = Cell(cells.value)
    current = new
    old = cells

    while old.next is not None:
        # copy the current cell
        ccopy = Cell(old.value)

        # add it
        current.next = ccopy

        # prepare for the next round
        current = ccopy
        old = old.next

    return new
```

I think this helps to understand how you accidentally reversed your cells: You walked the list forwards but the `C = Cell(A,C)` puts a new Cell before the old `C`, so that builds the new list from the end.

Comment: I really like this answer, it has a very elegant way of keeping things organized so +1.

Comment: Building your own linked list in the first place is part of the weird stuff. :)

Answer (score 3):

The lists print out backwards because as you are packing the OUTER elements into the new list FIRST.  As you continue to unwrap A, you add a wrapping to C.

The cleanest way to duplicate these lists might be to do a [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) of A and B (we'll call them C and D), and then set the deepest element in C (found by traversing until C.next==None) to reference D.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand, the best way to do it is have some sort of interim copy that allows me to reverse the order?

Comment: I thought through your suggestion and understand what you are getting at. I am letting python worry about the deep copy instead of trying to manage it myself, and then just attaching the two new lists at the tail/head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel it's a bit difficult to answer this question without seeing the definition of `Cell` -- but I think I see the mistake. Think of the list as a set of layers. The loop is starting with the innermost value of `C`. Every time you call `Cell` in the loop, it "wraps" that value with another `Cell` with the next value. The outermost `Cell` has the last value.

In other words,

```
C = Cell(8)
D = Cell(9, C)
E = Cell(10, D)
```

is equivalent to

```
E = Cell(10, Cell(9, Cell(8)))
```

Is that clear?

EDIT:

For the sake of completeness, here's another way to do it:

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, data, n = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = n

def list_concat_copy(A, B):
        head = Cell(A.data)
        C = head
        while A.next != None:
                A = A.next
                C.next = Cell(A.data)
                C = C.next
        C.next = Cell(B.data)
        C = C.next
        while B.next != None:
                B = B.next
                C.next = Cell(B.data)
                C = C.next
        return head


A = Cell(8, Cell(9, Cell(10)))
B = Cell(11, Cell(12, Cell(13)))
C = list_concat_copy(A, B)
```

Comment: I think I have that concept down, as you can see I was able to create linked lists in A and B of the form you suggested

Comment: But the point is that in the loop, you're doing it backwards, which is why the final list appears in reverse.

Comment: Miki's suggestion is to create a copy of the entire object using the deepcopy() function from the module copy. Then just have the tail of the copy of A point to the head of the copy of B.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def list_concat(x,y):
    if x.next is None:
        return Cell(x.data,y)
    else:
        return Cell(x.data,list_concat(x.next,y))
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Your answer contains only code. Could you please [edit] it and add some commentary on what it does and how it works? Thank you!